# Strange function fail when creating a metafile

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

Next function causes assertion failure, why?

```
void SimpleMeta(CDC* pDC)
{
CMetaFileDC meta;
meta.CreateEnhanced(pDC, CString("Square.emf"), CRect(0,0,100,100),CString("Simple square"));
meta.Rectangle(10,10,90,90);
meta.CloseEnhanced();
meta.DeleteDC();
}
```

Also, I have noticed while debugging that it fails when its called for the second time. It is called in OnDraw method. Why is OnDraw method called twice at all? Thank you.

Comment: there are so many reasons why you can get segmentation fault. During debug you should look at what variables are uninitialized or null.

Comment: Here's a quote from MSDN about DeleteDC, 'In general, do not call this function; the destructor will do it for you.'.

Comment: @Raxvan I checked everything, at least I think so..

Comment: @john Removed it, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your description parameter is incorrect. Here's a quote from MSDN

> The string pointed to by the lpszDescription parameter must contain a
>   null character between the application name and the picture name and
>   must terminate with two null characters —for example, "XYZ Graphics
>   Editor\0Bald Eagle\0\0," where \0 represents the null character. If
>   lpszDescription is NULL, there is no corresponding entry in the
>   enhanced-metafile header.

Also there is no need to wrap the literal strings with CString

```
meta.CreateEnhanced(pDC, 
    _T("Square.emf"), 
    CRect(0,0,100,100),
    _T("My program\0Simple square\0"));
```

for instance

Comment: Thanks, but it looks that there's something else. Tried that, but still the same... I even tried with NULL as description... It creates the meta file, but there's nothing in it...